# Logging into app using facebook account failed loading data

Tags: android, facebook-login

i'm trying to build an app where people can  logging using there facebook account, well i'v created the facebook app and provided a hashkey then i put all the required information into my android app the app id and the app secret. all i provided the package id and the activity where i'm using the logging activity. so i tried the app it gives me a popup asking for permission i granted it but i get a message saying "when data loading an error was occurred"
here is my code for the logging in process

```
public void signinByFacebookId() {
    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_AUTH_FACEBOOK, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    if (App.getInstance().authorize(response)) {

                        if (App.getInstance().getState() == ACCOUNT_STATE_ENABLED) {

                            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(AppActivity.this);

                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        } else {

                            App.getInstance().logout();
                            Toast.makeText(AppActivity.this, getText(R.string.account_blocked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            hidepDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("facebookId", facebookId);
            params.put("facebookEmail", facebookEmail);
            params.put("facebookName", facebookName);
            params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);

            return params;
        }
    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.ifsoft.secret" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AppActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" 
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

i've already searched here and anywhere else for a solution but couldn't find any. so any one can help please.

Comment: Any chance you could include the details of the VolleyError in your Toast when it happens?  That probably will indicate what's really going on.

Comment: the toast just say error while loading data. and i checked the android monitor so many times to see if an error will popup i didn't found anything

Comment: @ZouhairELALLALI set a breakpoint in `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` or print the error from VolleyError. Here is edited Toast --> `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` After that you can find the reason of error.

Comment: @MichaelKrause thinks to you i found the error it says UnknownHostException : unable to resolve host -Host URL- No adress associated with hostname